# Cannot curl from the same server when it has PREROUTING ip forwarding

Tags: iptables, curl, connection-refused

I have a Ubuntu web server that uses `iptables` PREROUTING to forward port `80` to `8000`.

So the web process listens on port `8000`. Now I want to make a curl from the same server to a web application running on it. But this issues a **Connection refused**:

```
$ curl http://my.webite.com/on/same/server
curl: (7) Failed connect to my.webite.com:80; Connection refused
```

`curl`-ing on port `8000` works (but it must work on port 80).

I also made sure that that web server listens on all interfaces (not only on the physical one):

```
$ netstat -ntl | grep LISTEN
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
...
```

The domain of my app (`my.webite.com`) also resolves to the physical interface IP.

Why do I get the **Connection refused**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PREROUTING chain doesn't apply to local (loopback) traffic.  You will need a redirect rule in the OUTPUT chain for it to work on the local system.

For example:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```