# Iptables DNAT rule curl connection refused

Tags: iptables, curl

After adding the following DNAT rule I'm getting connection refused when attempting to `curl 172.17.1.1:9000/v1/api`:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dst 172.17.1.1 --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.12.11.11:8000
```

I've read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1125212/why-does-iptables-block-this-curl-even-though-the-port-is-accepted) post and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/633003/cannot-curl-from-the-same-server-when-it-has-prerouting-ip-forwarding) post and seems like for curl we need to add an OUTPUT rule for the loopback? But how do we do this for DNAT rules?

I do have the following rules in place:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: do you have other firewalls like ufw? try this ```iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT```

Comment: Yes, I have some previous rules in place, the firewall rules are set to deny all traffic and we explicitly allow traffic . Updated the post.

Comment: @ZhivkoZhelev So i tried add `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` rule but still didn't work. What i did notice was that originally the request was immediately getting the connection refused error message when I curl. However, after adding the following output rule `iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dst 172.17.1.1 --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.12.11.11:8000` it wouldn't immediately return the error, but it now hangs on `trying 172.17.1.1 ...`. When I curl `172.12.11.11:8000` directly it works as well.

Comment: iptables also use order convention, so try removing the allowing rule now and set it before redirection rule using this ```--set-counters x``` x is place number

Comment: Understood that is why I used `-I` for inserting, that should insert the firewall rule to  the top and allow the rule to get hit first right? Which Allow rule did you want to remove `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` this one?

Comment: I assume that if you remove these 3 dropping rules your request will work, but first it needs to be accepted and I see you accepting only on loopback interface. So my suggestion is to try to arrange them properly and place the accept and redirect rule in upper position.